# changes in edit mode not showing in object/sculpt mode

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

i'm trying to make a simple character and i'm having some problems with the ankles i keep scaling down and no changes what so ever take effect in sculpt and object mode here's some pictures :
[image]

[image]

could someone help me with this and thank you very much :)

Comment: Welcome to the site. Probably this is caused by the smoothing effect of the Cathmull-Clark subdivision of the Multires. That said scaling effect is there but you don't see it because of smoothing between edge loop on the calf, scaled edge loop and one where the toes supposed to be. I'd say this model is too early to sculpt as it's too basic as of now and edge loops don't really follow body forms..

Comment: thank you sir :) . i tried few things like getting up the limit-edges of the feet and i actually saw some changes it's only when i scale them down and shrink it's surface that it doesn't follow. it just keeps the old dimensions, should i "delete higher" and start a new?

Comment: Most likely the best you can do is edit the base mesh itself, by adding and adjusting loopcuts. Yes this is far from good workflow but it might work (at least Multires has good chances to not face big problems). To add to my comment above,you should add a bit of base geometry between toes and ankles, to say the least. Note that the base topology in case of organic modeling is *very* important

Comment: thank you sir the loopcuts actually solved it. and i took your advices in consideration :)